# Extract data from Json url result php

Tags: php, json, bitcoin, dogecoin-api

I am trying to run a url for getting balance of a address.

URL: https://dogechain.info/api/v1/address/balance/DMr3fEiVrPWFpoCWS958zNtqgnFb7QWn9D

Which gives the JSON:

```
{
    "balance": "1682049.83191666",
    "success": 1
}
```

(Balance may vary time to time)

I am trying to extract the "balance" with the code:-

```
<?php
    $url = "https://dogechain.info/api/v1/address/balance/DMr3fEiVrPWFpoCWS958zNtqgnFb7QWn9D";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    $balance = json("balance")

    echo $balance
?>
```

But it returns nothing please help me =)

Comment: what about $json['balance']?

Answer (score 2):

You should do it like this

```
$balance = $json["balance"];
echo $balance;
```